# SQL: Conditional Insert/Update

Tags: sql, hana

Hi I am working with a table like the one below in SAP HANA:

```
Outcome  Value  Rating
Yes       0      null
Yes       20     null
No       -16     null
```

I need to populate the Rating column conditionally so that if:

```
Value > 15; Rating = 'High"
-15 <= Value <= 15; Rating = 'Medium" 
Value < -15; Rating = 'Low"
```

Is there anyway I can do this using an INSERT or UPDATE statement?

Comment: What have you tried so far? For example, if you searched online for "SQL conditional insert" [you'd likely find something helpful](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html).

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: I am working in SAP HANA for the first time attempting to process data for data mining, my SQL is rather weak as I never have used it much.

Comment: I have tried using UPDATE with a WHERE clause with a SELECT statement containing the condition.

Comment: Hana has an `upsert` statement: http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/fc06a7751910149892c0d09be21a38/content.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `MSSQL`, this is a good use for the [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement:

```
RATING = CASE
            WHEN Value > 15 THEN 'High'
            WHEN Value BETWEEN -15 AND 15 THEN 'Medium'
            ELSE 'Low'
         END
```

This assumes that `Value` is an int and not some other type.

Example for an `INSERT` statement:

```
DECLARE @Value int = 10,
        @Rating varchar(10)

SELECT  @Rating = CASE
                    WHEN @Value > 15 THEN 'High'
                    WHEN @Value BETWEEN -15 AND 15 THEN 'Medium'
                    ELSE 'Low'
                  END

INSERT INTO Table
    (Outcome, Value, Rating)
SELECT
    Outcome = 'Yes',
    Value = @Value,
    Rating = @Rating
```

and `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE  Table
SET     Rating = CASE
                    WHEN Value > 15 THEN 'High'
                    WHEN Value BETWEEN -15 AND 15 THEN 'Medium'
                    ELSE 'Low'
                 END
WHERE   UniqueID = 1
```

Comment: and how to use this case in an insert query?

Comment: @MohamedElHousseine I have added an example. If you want to use it inline, it depends on how you're receiving the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql routines to handle the conditional code, here is a example of the routine you are looking for.

```
CREATE FUNCTION  `myfunc` (`value` INT) RETURNS VARCHAR( 10 ) 
IF value >=15 THEN RETURN  'High';
ELSEIF value >= -15 AND value <15 THEN RETURN  'Medium';
ELSEIF value < -15 THEN RETURN  'Low';
END IF ;
```

you can use this routine in your mysql code like

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` VALUES('Yes',5,myfunc(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table_name set Rating = case  when Value<-15 then 'low' when
(Value>-15 and Value<15) then 'medium' when Value>15 then 'high' end
```

Using case with update statement should solve your problem